# kind of 3d rotation effect, is it possible with css3, html5 and javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im wondering if that effect of rotating menu is possible to achive with technologies from topic? Here's link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdsv-y9LUa4&hd=1

Or only way out is using flash? Could someone provide links to some relevant plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its completely possible!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

And look at it here in action :)

http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/canvask3d/k3d_test.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.